# Find GPU resource allocation on virtual server

Tags: nvidia, virtualization, gpu

I have been provided a virtual server, which runs Ubuntu 14.04. I'm accessing it using PuTTY. The server should have a NVIDIA GRID K2 GPU, but I'm having some issues using it in Python/C++ with the [Caffe library.](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) In particular, I get the errors `modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found` and  `Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (38 vs. 0)  no CUDA-capable device is detected`.

I'd like to check that the GPU is actually allocated to the virtual machine. How can I do that using the command line?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I think I probably reinstalled CUDA, made up all the paths were setup correctly in `~/.bashrc`, ran `source ~/.bashrc`. That fixed my issue. For finding the GPU resource allocation, I ended up using the `nvidia-smi` command a lot.

Comment: Oh great job, thanks! Would you like to post an answer below to help others with this issue?

Comment: Sure, did it work for you?

Comment: I didn't have this problem myself - I'm just trying to make the site more useful in general. More answers = more help for folks trying to use Ubuntu :)